# Chrome for Android works differently from Desktop version with HTML select tag

Tags: android, html, html-select

I'm using Select tag. when approaching by PC, I see all the options to choose from. When approaching by Android, I have to touch the select tag and then a window is popped up with the options.
Is there a way to just get a drop-down (as it works on Windows)?

I have to see four/five options of the select tag without to open the popup clicking on.

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard way Android handles `select` elements in WebViews. If you want different behavior, you'll have to use a select box library such [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).